# My proof that the boundary of a set is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I have written a proof that the boundary of a set is closed. I am unsure if it is valid or not, so any feedback is appreciated.

**Problem**: Prove bd $S$ is closed.

**Proof:** Consider $\mathbb{R} \setminus $bd $S$. Sps. $x \in $ $\mathbb{R} \setminus $bd $S$. Thus $N(x ; \epsilon)$ intersects in only $S$ or $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$.  Therefore all neighborhoods based at $x$ are all contained in $S$ or $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$, which means that $\mathbb{R} \setminus $bd $S$ is open. Thus bd $S$ is closed.

I'm unsure if my logic in the middle had any errors, so it'll be great if someone can let me know how I'm doing.

Comment: You have to prove that $N(x;\epsilon)$ only intersects $S$ or $\Bbb{R}-S$. Think of the definition of a boundary point.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem says "Prove bd S is closed for [b]some[/b] S⊂R"?  You appear to be trying to prove that "Prove bd S is closed for [b]S⊂R[/b].
. 
.

Comment: @florence If $x$ is a boundary point, then all neighborhoods based at $x$ intersect at $S$ and the complement of $S$. Since we are excluding the boundary points and considering $\mathbb{R} \setminus $ bd $S$, we can conclude that it lies only in $S$ or $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$. Is this correct?

Comment: "Therefore all neighborhoods based at $x$ are all contained in $S$ or $\mathbb{R}\setminus{S}$" - No, your assumption $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus{ \text{bd} S}$ only gives you *one* neighborhood $N(x ; \epsilon)$ which is either contained in $S$ or in $\mathbb{R}\setminus{S}$. But this is ok. You could try now to show that $N(x ; \epsilon) \subseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus{\text{bd} S}$ to show that $\mathbb{R} \setminus{\text{bd} S}$ is open.

Comment: The "if...then" in that first statement is backwards (you want to say that if $x$ intersects with both $S$ and $\Bbb{R}-S$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then $x$ would be a boundary point), but you have the idea. Details like that should definitely be included in your proof. And be sure not to forget to say "for all" and "there exists" when appropriate, particularly when dealing with $\epsilon$'s.

Comment: What's your definition of the boundary actually?